# Unable to detect adb version, adb

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, adb

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 32bit on a 32bit machine and the latest version of Android Studio with all packages downloaded from SDK manager (without the Intel atom, TV, Wear).

When I try to run or debug the App (the default simplest `hello world`) the console show these errors and prompt a pop-up with:

```
ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb" and click 'Restart':
```

Console:

```
13.31.35 Unable to detect adb version, adb output:
/home/user/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: 1:
/home/user/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: Syntax error: ")"unexpected

13.31.37 Error running app: Unable to obtain debug bridge
```

I already tried:

```
killall adb
adb: no such process
```

and

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

But the error still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the platform-tools were for a 64bit machine, after replacing those with this version:
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip
Android Studio recognizes the adb.
But after AVD chosen, another error occurs:

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED, to use them
you will have to do at least one of the following:
- Use the '-force-32bit' option when invoking 'emulator'.
- Set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to 'true' in your environment.
Either one will allow you to use the 32-bit binaries, but please be
aware that these will disappear in a future Android SDK release.
Consider moving to a 64-bit Linux system before that happens.
```